# Properly filtering array of objects with multiple conditions and an array

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm creating a Todo App as an exercise in learning PostgreSQL and functional programming in javascript. The idea is there can be multiple containers each with separate filter settings, each reading from a master list of Todos, then each container displays it's results based on it's filter settings. This is really all done in React-Redux, and Nodejs, but I made the examples below to better illustrate the problem.

The Data:

```
// Example todos
let a = {
  added: "2021-02-01T05:00:00.000Z",
  completed: null,
  description: "This is just a test.",
  name: "testing",
  tags: [],
  todo_id: 3,
}
let b = {
  added: "2021-02-01T05:00:00.000Z",
  completed: null,
  description: "This is just a test.",
  name: "testing",
  tags: ["one", "two"],
  todo_id: 4
}
let c = {
  added: "2021-02-01T05:00:00.000Z",
  completed: null,
  description: "This is just a test.",
  name: "tesin",
  tags: ["one"],
  todo_id: 5
}
let d = {
  added: "2021-02-01T05:00:00.000Z",
  completed: '2021-03-01T05:00:00.000Z',
  description: "This is just a test.",
  name: "testing",
  tags: ["two", "testing"],
  todo_id: 6
}

// Example filter_group 
// This is just to show what the initial state looks like in my React app
const filter_groups = {
  "main": {
    byTag: 'two',
    byName: '',
    byCompleted: true
  }
}

// Object.keys(filter_groups).map() passes the filter settings down as props
// Just stuck it in a variable for the example
const filter = filter_groups['main']

// Putting example Todos in array
const todo_list = [a,b,c,d]
```

The current solution is pretty simple, ugly, and inefficient. It applies each filter one at a time:

```
// ------- CURRENT SOLUTION ------- 

// if user is trying to filter byCompleted, then filter todo_list
// else do nothing todo_list and pass it to the next filter 
// (similar thing applies down the chain)
const byCompleted = filter.byCompleted === true ?
  todo_list.filter ( (t) => {
    return t.completed !== null
  })
  :
  todo_list


//IF user is trying to filter byTag...
const byTag = filter.byTag !== '' ?
  // THEN filter the byCompleted array above
  byCompleted.filter( (t) => {
    // IF there are tags on the Todo...
    let matches = t.tags ?
      // THEN filter for matches
      t.tags.filter( (tag) => {
        return tag === filter.byTag
      }) 
      : 
      // ELSE make this an empty array
      []

    // return any Todos with match
    return matches.length > 0
  })
  :
  byCompleted

// IF user is trying to filter byName...
const byName = filter.byName !== '' ?
  // THEN filter byTag Todos
  byTag.filter( (t) => {
    return t.name === P.filter.byName
  })
  :
  byTag

console.log(byName);
```

I really want to know if there's a way to apply the entire filter all at once. In the example you'll see the filter is set to `byTag: 'two', byComplete: true` which makes the console print out only one result. My past attempts at getting things to work with one filter pass would return everything with the `two` tag.

I tried looking at the documentation and saw there's more going on in the filter function, but it just didn't click, and I couldn't find any examples that fit my use case very well.

Edit: Here's it all on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-almeida-cdz65?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned function programming in your question.

The code below takes a currying approach to solving your filtering problems.

Once the individual filters are established, it is a simple matter of chaining them together. Each filter function will return an array for the next function to operate upon.

Note: I had to infer some details.

```js
let a = { added: "2021-02-01T05:00:00.000Z", completed: null, description: "This is just a test.", name: "testing", tags: [], todo_id: 3, } 
let b = { added: "2021-02-01T05:00:00.000Z", completed: null, description: "This is just a test.", name: "testing", tags: ["one", "two"], todo_id: 4 } 
let c = { added: "2021-02-01T05:00:00.000Z", completed: null, description: "This is just a test.", name: "tesin", tags: ["one"], todo_id: 5 } 
let d = { added: "2021-02-01T05:00:00.000Z", completed: '2021-03-01T05:00:00.000Z', description: "This is just a test.", name: "testing", tags: ["two", "testing"], todo_id: 6 } 

const filter_groups = { "main": { byTag: 'two', byName: '', byCompleted: true } }
const filter = filter_groups['main']

const todo_list = [a,b,c,d]

let byTag = td => td.tags.includes(filter.byTag);
let byName = td => filter.name ? td.tags.includes(filter.name) : true;
let byCompleted = td => filter.byCompleted ? td.completed !== null : false ;

let result = todo_list.filter(byTag).filter(byName).filter(byCompleted);

console.log(result);
```

EDIT: OP asked to do this in one code block. That solution follows:

```js
let a = { added: "2021-02-01T05:00:00.000Z", completed: null, description: "This is just a test.", name: "testing", tags: [], todo_id: 3, };
let b = { added: "2021-02-01T05:00:00.000Z", completed: null, description: "This is just a test.", name: "testing", tags: ["one", "two"], todo_id: 4 }; 
let c = { added: "2021-02-01T05:00:00.000Z", completed: null, description: "This is just a test.", name: "tesin", tags: ["one"], todo_id: 5 }; 
let d = { added: "2021-02-01T05:00:00.000Z", completed: '2021-03-01T05:00:00.000Z', description: "This is just a test.", name: "testing", tags: ["two", "testing"], todo_id: 6 }; 

const todo_list = [a,b,c,d];

const filter_groups = { "main": { tags: 'two', name: '', completed: true } };

let result2 = todo_list.filter(td=>{
  return Object.entries(filter_groups['main'])
    .filter(([k,v])=>!!v!=false)
    .map(f=>!!td[f[0]])
    .every(f=>f==true);
});

console.log(result2);
```

The OP also mentioned a concern about performance in his original code and my "three step" solution.

In order to offer confidence to just code the way you normally would, I ran a series of tests using jsben.ch.com. The image below shows the OP's original code consistently coming in at #2 or #1. The "three step" solution shares that result. The bottom line is that more steps doesn't necessarily equate to poorer performance. If you can get the site to cooperate, run the tests several times to get an idea of the differences in performance. [JSBEN.CH Tests](https://jsben.ch/iYFPG)

**Take these results with a grain of salt** - good for showing comparisons but not much else.

[image]

Comment: That looks so much cleaner and is really useful answer. I had to edit `let byCompleted = td => filter.byCompleted ? td.completed !== null : true ;`, but I don't think I made that very clear in my post. Sorry but I'm also kind of worrying about speed (not so much because it's important to the application, just curious) and this looks like it would still make 3 separate passes? I know with each pass things will decrease in size and all, but still, ideally I would like to know how to get this all to go with one pass if possible.

Comment: Individual steps is the essence of functional programming. As you've discovered, writing this in one big block get messy specifically because of the interdependency of the conditionals. I would buy code that is cleaner and easy to maintain over code that is a few milliseconds faster any day of the week.

Comment: I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! This has been an awesome learning experience, I'm really surprised my original solution did so well. I really feel like I don't have a solid grasp on this kind of thing though. Do you have an recommendations in terms of resources for learning more about this kind of stuff?

Comment: I'm glad to help. I struggle with the idea of "resources for learning" because I am a strong believer in human-to-human interaction as the finest learning method around. Self learning without a mentor/teacher is limited in its reach. With that said, I'm clearly not found of tutorial sites with their contrived examples that don't really reflect the real world. So, I suppose the best resource I can offer appears in the left panel of [this web site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). Browse through the topics in both the tutorials and references. Then go for one of them!